# CloudFront functions "invocation" as relates to pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

The CloudFront functions [pricing documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/) says:

> You are charged for the total number of invocations across all your functions. CloudFront Functions counts an invocation each time it starts executing in response to a CloudFront event globally.

Does this mean that executing multiple functions from a single event is considered a single "invocation"? In other words, if I have two functions that are tied to `viewer-request` for a distribution, will I be charged one invocation or two invocations if both functions execution in response to a single viewer request for a single URL?

The definition above, referring to "starts executing … a CloudFront event" and "across all your functions" sounds like I will only be charged for a single invocation, regardless of how many functions execute.

Comment: Based on experience, the UI and documentation, you can only have 1 Function or Lambda@edge attached to a single "viewer-request" event for a cache behavior.  If you had separate attachments for "viewer-request" and "origin-request", you may have 2 invocations for 1 user request to your distribution, depending on caching and whether the request results in a cache hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the phrase "starts executing in response to a CloudFront event globally" refers to each function's *execution*, *not* the event itself, each function execution would be counted as a separate invocation.

While both functions are executed in response to a single viewer request for a single URL, you would still be charged for two invocations.

The [function itself](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html) might be optimized to improve your cache hit ratio with an optimal [cache key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/understanding-the-cache-key.html), but... that would still necessitate for the function to be called.

---

As noted by [LeeCookson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528826/leecookson) in the comments:

> If a function is attached to "`viewer-request`", it will fire on every request, since that event occurs before the cache layer.
> This event is often used to craft a custom cache key, so must occur before the cache layer.
>
> "`viewer-origin`" fires after the cache layer, so cache optimization could result in cost reduction on that invocation.

Comment: "… refers … not the event itself …" So "event" doesn't refer to "event", or rather, they are throwing around the word "event" in an overloaded sense to try to clarify what "invocation" means, making the explanation even more confusing. In short, if I rephrase what I understand that you're saying, when a user views a page I'll be charged more if I split the logic up into two functions than if I were to combine the same logic into one function.

Comment: @GarretWilson It does look that way indeed. I don't have a way to test it right now, but it is worth for you to make a test and validate that.

Comment: If a function is attached to "viewer-request", it will fire on every request since that event occurs before the cache layer.  This event is often used to craft a custom cache key, so must occur before the cache layer.  "viewer-origin" fires after the cache layer, so cache optimization could result in cost reduction on that invocation.

Comment: @LeeCookson Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Hopefully, Garret can answer to your other comment.